# Test class isnt covering for Site class

Tags: unit-test

Following method isnt covering in test class:

```
   @AuraEnabled
public static String login(String username, String password, String startUrl, Boolean isEnglish) {
    String currentuserId;
    String tester;
    try{
        ApexPages.PageReference lgn = Site.login(username, password, startUrl);

        if (isEnglish == null || isEnglish)
            lgn.getParameters().put('language','en_CA');
        else 
            lgn.getParameters().put('language','fr');

        currentuserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        User currentUserInfo = [select Id, LanguageLocaleKey from User where username = :username];
        tester = currentuserId + ' ' + currentUserInfo.Id;
        system.debug('USER ' + currentUserInfo);
        if (currentUserInfo != null){
            //CRUD udpate #Unfuddle 311
            if(Schema.SobjectType.User.isAccessible() && Schema.SobjectType.User.isUpdateable()){

            if(isEnglish == null || isEnglish){
                currentUserInfo.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
            }else{
                currentUserInfo.LanguageLocaleKey = 'fr';
            }

            update currentUserInfo;
            }else{
                  throw new AuraHandledException('Insufficient privileges to update a User, Contact System Administrator!');
            }


        }
        aura.redirect(lgn);

        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        //return ex.getMessage();
        return Label.S360_PIF_Login_Error;
    }
```

### }

```
    @isTest
          public class S360_LightningLoginFormController_Test {
     public static testmethod void testLoginForm(){
    //create User
    User u = new User(
        ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name ='Business System Administrator'].Id,
        LastName = 'last',
        Email = 'test@gmail.com',
        Username = 'test1@gmail.com' + System.currentTimeMillis(),
        CompanyName = 'TEST',
        Title = 'title',
        Alias = 'alias',
        TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
        EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
        LanguageLocaleKey ='fr',
        LocaleSidKey ='fr_CA');
     insert u;


      SiteRegisterController controller = new SiteRegisterController();
    controller.username = 'test@force.com';
    controller.email = 'test@force.com';
    controller.communityNickname = 'test';
    // registerUser always returns null when the page isn't accessed as a guest user
    System.assert(controller.registerUser() == null);
    controller.password = 'abcd1234';
    controller.confirmPassword = 'abcd123';
    System.assert(controller.registerUser() == null);
   //Site.createPortalUser('test@force.com','abcd1234','url');
 //Site.createPortalUser(u, accountId, password)

    S360_LightningLoginFormController.login(u.Username,'sunlife','url',true);
```

[image]

Comment: What is the error it is throwing that you are catching?

Answer (score 0):

I think the test class that you cited passes `true` for the last parameter in the login method.  This is why the else condition is not met/covered.  I could be wrong but i think to raise code coverage you may want to consider revising your test class so that it sets up a second user:

```
...
User user2 = new User(
        ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name ='Business System Administrator'].Id,
        LastName = 'last',
        Email = 'test2@gmail.com',
        Username = 'test2@gmail.com' + System.currentTimeMillis(),
        CompanyName = 'TEST',
        Title = 'title',
        Alias = 'alias',
        TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
        EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
        LanguageLocaleKey ='fr',
        LocaleSidKey ='fr_CA');
     insert user2;
...
```

then you could call login method a second time from your test, ensuring that the else condition could be met.  like this:

```
...

    S360_LightningLoginFormController.login(u.Username,'sunlife','url',true);
S360_LightningLoginFormController.login(user2.Username,'sunlife','url',false);

...
```